# Perron root of convex combination of nonnegative matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-hulls, nonnegative-matrices

Given (irreducible) nonnegative matrices $A_i$ and a convex weighting $\hat{w}$ (i.e. a nonnegative set of reals ${w}$ s.t. $\sum_i w_i$) what can we deduce about the Perron root of $\sum_i w_i A_i$, in terms of the Perron roots of $A_i$?
The classical theorems require $A_i$ to all be symmetric (Hermitian) or diagonal.

What can we say about bounds for this Perron root? Approximations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the dominant eigenspace of each component (nonnegative irreducible) matrix is known, the results of [L. Yu. Kolotilina](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1022450418421) apply here. In particular, to restate their Theorem 5:

$$
\rho\left(\sum_i A_i\right) \geq \sum_i \alpha_i \rho(A_i)
$$

in which the coefficients $\alpha_i$ are given by a product of ratios of the left and right eigenvectors for $A_i$ as can be seen on page 10. Within, they also discuss the case of equality in which all left and right eigenvectors of $A_i$, namely $u^{(i)}, v^{(i)}$ satisfy $u^{(i)} \cdot v^{(i)} = c \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, not much, I am afraid. You have obviously $\rho(\sum_i A_i)\geq \max_i \rho(A_i)$ but that seems to be all. In particular, you don't have   $\rho(\sum_i A_i)\leq \sum_i \rho(A_i)$ as you would if the matrices were symmetric.

For example (letting $\epsilon\approx 0$ be a small positive number) with $A_1=\pmatrix{\epsilon & 1\\ \epsilon& \epsilon}$ and $A_2=A_1^t$ you have $\rho(A_i)\approx 0$ but $\rho(A_1+A_2)\approx 1$ while for $A_1=\pmatrix{1 &\epsilon\\ \epsilon& \epsilon}$, $A_2=\pmatrix{\epsilon & \epsilon\\ \epsilon& 1}$, you have $\rho(A_i)\approx 1 \approx \rho(A_1+A_2)$.

EDIT: For the lower bound stated in the beginning of my post, it may be shown from the Collatz-Wielandt characterization of the Perron value.

In dim $d$, one sets for $x\in {\Bbb R}_+^d$, $x\neq 0$ and understanding that $\inf\{+\infty,a\}=a$:
$$ \lambda_A(x) = \inf_i \frac{(Ax)_i}{x_i}$$
Then C-W tells us that $\rho(A)=\max\{ \lambda_A(x) : x\in {\Bbb R}_+^d, |x|=1\}$. For positive matrices $A$ and $B$ we clearly  have $\lambda_{A+B}(x) \geq \max\{ \lambda_A(x), \lambda_B(x)\}$ and the claim follows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't think it would change much but possibly worth adding that my matrices are substochastic too.

Comment: @JacobA If substochastic means what I think it means: rows summing to at most one, it does not change the outcome as I believe you can simply scale to obtain that property.

Comment: Yes this is precisely what I meant and for the same reason I agree. To ask for further clarification, *why* do we get that max bound (we also get an analogous min bound, right?) Is there a geometric picture I can think about here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the analogous min bound? For the max, true that it is perhaps not that obvious. It comes from e.g. the Collatz-Wielandt characterization of the Perron value. If you wish I can add some lines to describe that.

Comment: I know I've come across the Collatz-Wielandt before but didn't see the application here. I can try on my own to show it first. By a min bound I was also hoping for, e.g. $\rho(\sum_i A_i) \geq \min_i \rho(A_i)$

Comment: OK, I'll add some details for C-W. For the min, that is automatic given the max bound ;-)

Comment: if you are interested in another bound, I've found a paper that I've posted as another answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: @JacobA Thanks for the link. Right now I only have access to the abstract. It looks interesting, but in the first result  seems to have a rather strong hypothesis: That the leading Perron projections for the $A_i$'s are identical, not that scalar product are the same (the scalar product of the left and right eigenvector are usually normalized to 1). The  second result goes beyond but still seems to require information about eigenvectors which perhaps may be difficult to obtain (without calculating them).

Comment: Upon reflection, these strong hypotheses turned out to be OK for me. This is because I decompose my matrices into a stochastic and a diagonal piece. For me, the stochastic piece is the same for all matrices $A^{(l)}$ which works out well in their theorem 1, 3 and 5. It is typically easier to find the non-trivial (e.g. left/right depending on convention) eigenvector of a *stochastic* matrix, and of course in that case $\rho(A)=1$ as well which simplifies matters.